# Transformation in convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I have a small problem with the correction of one of the exercises in my mid-term exam. Please have a look at the screenshot below:

[Convergence of series exercise (c)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUztU.png)

I understand why the quotient criterion was used and everything else as well, but what I don't get is the last expression. I do not see exactly how the $\exp(n-1)$ is gone ... Where did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{e^{n-1}}{e^n}=e^{n-1-n}=e^{-1}=\frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: Did not see that, perhaps if had "e" instead of exp I would have seen it. Thank you :)

Comment: I see. I' ve been in that situation many times, so I' ve decided to use the $e$ symbol when the expressions involved are not to complex to be in the exponent.